# How do I web scrape from 5 different webpages to create a string for a validation url if the content on the pages keeps changing every 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I've entered a competition and have answered all the questions except this "Bonus: Elite" question. It has five links, all with the same URL, the only difference being the "clock" part of it.
e.g.

- **1st link = https....clock-pt1**
- **2nd link = https....clock-pt2**                 etc.

When that URL is clicked, it comes up with a code and my plan was to gather these codes together for the validation URL (a separate sixth URL) - **https....clock-pts**. The problem is that it's programmed so that the contents of the links will change after 10 seconds and that isn't enough time for me to gather all the codes, put it in the validation link to get the answer code.
People have told me to use Python Request, but I can't download that because it isn't compatible with my laptop.

Can anybody help?

*If I'm not making sense, let me know (kindly, please)*

Comment: It can be done with `urllib` and `threading`

Comment: @t.m.adam How would I do that, then?

Comment: Are you asking us to write your code, for your competition entry, for you?

Comment: @roelofs Not at all. I'm sorry if that's the way it came across. I've just never heard of urllib.

Comment: @roelofs and t.m.adam Thank you for the help. I'll use the input to try and figure it out. Again - sorry if I caused disruptions

Comment: No need to apologize for asking a question, this is a qna site after all. `urllib` (`urllib2` for Python2.x) and `threading` are both standard libs, which means you don't have to install anything.  But if you havent heard of `urllib` this might be too hard for you. I think you should start with a tutorial, and of course read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html)